# Combining Clojure defprotocol and defrecord

Tags: clojure, protocols

As far as I can tell, if I want to define a protocol (`defprotocol`) that will only be implemented by one `defrecord`, I still have to define the protocol first, then define the `defrecord` that implements it:

```
(defprotocol AProtocol
  (a-method [this])
  (b-method [this that]))

(defrecord ARecord [a-field b-field]
  AProtocol
  (a-method [this] ...)
  (b-method [this that] ...))
```

Is there no way to combine the two, perhaps with an "anonymous" protocol?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use ordinary functions?

Comment: @Jonas: I may want to refactor the protocol to a `defprotocol` later so that others records can implement it, but at the present time, I am not sure. I guess I can always change the ordinary functions into protocol functions as part of the refactoring. I also can't "override" a built-in function like `count` without implementing a protocol, or I will shadow the default binding.

Comment: A protocol function named `count` will shadow the built-in too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't do this. A "private" or "anonymous" protocol that your record implements is just reinventing a pointless version of OOP in a language that has better options. Define a regular old function that operates on your records; there's no reason it has to be physically attached to them.

If you later want to refactor it to be a protocol instead...it's easy! The client won't be able to tell the difference, because protocol function calls look just like regular function calls.

Comment: What happens if the new function is the same as an existing "core" function? Won't it shadow the core function?

Comment: in that case you would have to namespace qualify it. my/+ vs +

Comment: @Ralph see my comment on your question. Yes, it will shadow the core function, but using a protocol would too. If you really wanted it to be anonymous, you could attach the function as a field of the record: `(defrecord Foo [count-me]) ... (let [x (Foo. (constantly 1))] ... ((:count-me x) x))`

Comment: Sometimes I use the approach in the question because I want to use a deftype/defrecord instead of a clojure map and I find the syntax in the deftype/defrecord methods easier than writing plain old functions when I have lots of fields because instead having to put (.a-field x) in the functions, I can just use a-field which reads better.

Answer (score 4):

Yes that is completely correct :)

The main reason for this would be if you expect others to want to extend your protocol later.